# JS Set background image of span

Tags: javascript, html

**JS:**

```
function getItem() {
  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 110) + 1);
  Weapon = "Opening..."
  document.getElementById("Weapon").innerHTML = Weapon;

  if (rand < 3) {
      document.getElementById("Weapon").innerHTML = "Item Type One";
  } else if (rand > 2 && rand < 5) {
      document.getElementById("Weapon").innerHTML = "Item Type Two";
  }
  // Continues onward etc...
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="getItem()">Get Item</button>
<span id="image"><!-- Display an image here? --></span>
You Unboxed: <span id="Weapon">Nothing</span>
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to also set the source of an image in this HTML from my Javascript code. So if I get "Item One" it will display that image in my HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an array containing the paths to your images such as

`var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png"]`

Then get a reference to your image element, then set its source to the image in the array accordingly

`myImage.src = images[0]` for example

Edit:

So you said you have an array of images like this

`var images = ["stub.png", "Other.png"];`

I see that you are using a `<span>` to display your images. So you need to get a reference to that `<span>` element.

`var myImage = document.getElementById("weapon");`

Since you are using a `<span>` element to display your image, not a `<img>`, so to show your image, you do this

`myImage.style.backroundImage = url(images[n]);` with n being the image index corresponding to your if/else. You should use `<img>` to display your image instead.

Comment: so how would i do this exactly? i have added my images to the array so how do i display it? Im not that good with Js & Html but i understand it.

Comment: Just create a variable and store the reference to your `<img>` element using the `document.getElementById()` method, then in your if/else, change the `src` property on the variable that you use to store the reference to your `<img>` element. Make sense?

Comment: Btw, you use a `<span>` element to display your image or `<img>` element?

Comment: so i have a var images = ["stub.png", "Other.png"]

Comment: and i have myImage.src = images[0] in my if else statement

Comment: Dont worry, I am editing my answer for you. It'll be a minute

Answer (score 1):

There is no image tag and url, how can you display different images, there is no second argument in setTimeout function. Here i can help you

```
<br/>
You Unboxed: <img id="Weapon" src=''/> 

function openCase() {
    var Gun = Math.floor((Math.random() * 110) + 1);
    console.log(Gun);
    var weaponarray = [] // create your image array here
    Weapon = //some initial image
    document.getElementById("Weapon").src=Weapon;
    setInterval(callback,500) // every 500 mili sec call function
}

   function callback(){
    var Gun = Math.floor((Math.random() * 110) + 1);
    if (Gun < 3) {
             Weapon = weaponarray[Gun];
             document.getElementById("Weapon").src=Weapon;
       } 
       else if (Gun > 2 && Gun < 5) {
        Weapon = weaponarray[Gun];
        document.getElementById("Weapon").src=Weapon;
       }    
    }
```